# selenium RC ruby, wait for hidden element to appear?

Tags: ruby, selenium

How can I wait for a hidden element to appear on the page?

I tried `seleum.is_element_present` but it dosent seem to be working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is the is_visible method. Below will wait for 30 seconds to become visible

```
!30.times{ break if (@selenium.is_visible("locator") rescue false); sleep 1 }
```

Answer (score 0):

`wait_for_element(locator, options={})`

Wait for an element to be present (the wait in happenning browser side).

Comment: present means it exists in the DOM, it doesn't mean it's visible

Answer (score 0):

Came across the same problem using Watir, *present?* only works if element is visible. To wait for an invisible element to appear you can do this in Watir

```
Watir::Wait.until { browser.div(:class => "loaded").exists? }
```

*exists?* returns true if element is in the DOM, doesn't care about visibility